# SSL error & hostname not found

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, afnetworking

My app is using Alamofire to deal with API call.
I sometimes received the following error :

1. The network connection was lost
2. A server with the specified hostname would not be found
3. An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server can not be made

They often occurred when the phone screen goes dark and I come back on the app.

I would like to know where they come from and if I can hide them to my user.

I do have an exception in the app security for my server subdomain. Maybe I'm not doing something right when my app goes in background...

Comment: could you tell more about the device's reception, the DNS, and type of SSL? any other environmental conditions, like e.g. VPN, proxy, etc...?  can you post some code of how you've built the request up?

Comment: Is this happening right when device wakes up? Perhaps the app is trying to connect to your API before the connection is established after waking? Maybe take a look at the Reachability class to detect the presence of a network before making the API call.